# Google Calendar is importing my events to Sheet but it's not writing it into the sheet correctly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

I am using as a master tracking spreadsheet so all new details added after the calendar event import get mixed up when a new event is added to the sheet. HELP. I need to keep the events and new columns of data in the same row. I have 14 rows of data.

```
function importCalendar(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Calendar Import'); //Target sheet for events
  var calendarName = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue(); //name of calendar ex. calendar@gmailcom
  var start = sheet.getRange('C3').getValue(); //to date
  var end = sheet.getRange('C4').getValue();  //from date

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarName); 
  if(calendar) {var calendarId = calendar.getId();} 
  if(!calendar) { 
   var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0]; 
   var calendarId = calendarName; 
   } 

   var events = calendar.getEvents(start, end); 
   var eventDetails = []; 
   for(var i = 0; i<events.length; i++){ 
   eventDetails.push([events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getStartTime(), 
 events[i].getDescription()]);
 
  }

        //write calendar details to spreadsheet and where my problem is//
    var startRow = 8;
    var startCol = 2; 
   for(var j = 0; j<eventDetails.length; j++){
    var tempRange = sheet.getRange(startRow+j, startCol, 1, eventDetails[j].length);
    var eventArray = Array(eventDetails[j]);
    tempRange.setValues(eventArray);
  }
   return eventDetails;
  }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I am using as a master tracking spreadsheet so all new details added after the calendar event import get mixed up when a new event is added to the sheet.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sure, Calendar events are imported into columns 2-6. But Columns 7-13 also contain data. When new events are imported, columns 2-6 no longer line up with the data in columns 7-13. I suspect when the new events are imported it's not getting the entire sheet or range.So it's sorting new events by data and ignoring columns 7-13 in the process of that sort.

Comment: It does not seem to be an issue in the code, what exactly do you mean by **"it's not writing it into the sheet correctly"**? Do you want to write it in a specific format?

Comment: Thank you, yes, when the new events are added to the sheet, it's re-sorted and the other -columns 7-13 no longer match up. How do I get it to know that all those rows need to stay together?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your current situation and your goal from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. But when I could correctly understand about your goal, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, if you were doing this manually you would insert an entire new row before entering the data so the rows would move together, yes?